# How to hide keyboard when return key is hit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Trying to hide the iOS keyboard when the return key is hit, but instead it halts and gives me the error seen in the image. Here's the code I'm using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UITextField!

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ scoreText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't delegate a textField in order to use that method. First, your class must include the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol:

```
class yourClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ... }
```

And in the `viewDidLoad()` method, add this as well:

```
scoreText.delegate = self
```

And then you have to change this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ scoreText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

to this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ scoreText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

Final code:

```
class yourClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scoreText.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ scoreText: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing()
        return true
    }
}
```

If this is not working, the problem is not the `textFieldShouldReturn()` function. Please check your outlet connections.

Comment: Having this problem: http://i.imgur.com/PAWVdrb.png By the way, why do I need to delegate the TextField and not a label, button etc.?

Comment: @stevetheipad 1 - because the **textFieldShouldReturn** function is included in **UITextFieldDelegate** ; 2 - try to add your argument:  **self.view.endEditing(true)**, I've probably missed that in my answer

Comment: Added the (true) but it stills says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on the AppDelegate.

Comment: Then the problem here isn't the class!

Comment: Deleted that text field, re made it and now it works. Weird! Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is great!:)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: No luck, same problem.

Comment: @stevetheipad Did you set your view controller to follow UITextField delegate?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean an IBOutlet? If so, yes I added one of those for the UITextField.

Comment: @stevetheipad crashes in app delegate regarding text fields usually means you have lingering outlets not connected. Check your "Referencing Outlets" in story board and if possible show us the bug in console not just the code

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4 or 5 , You can use like :

1. create a project
2. add UITextField & connect to ViewController
3. implement UITextFieldDelegate to ViewController
4. Initialize the UITextField delegate
5. Add textFieldShouldReturn method in ViewController
6. Here is full code

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    //Connect to text field
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

       //must initialize delegate
       scoreText.delegate = self
     }

    //add method
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
       return true
    }  

   }
   ```

Comment: better than others, TY